# When should I use catkin workspace?

Tags: ros, rviz, moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I dont undestand why should I use catkin worksapce. When I export a package from Moveit Setup Assistant I move it on `opt/ros/indigo/share` and I launch it with `roslaunch di/rec/tory/demo.launch`. But the name of the exported package  **must** be the same as the urdf package.

If  I move the exported file from Moveit Setup Assistant to `home/name/catkin_ws/src` and run `cakin_make` and launch it with `roslaunch home/name/catkin_ws/src/<package_name>/launch/demo.launch` it gives many errors.

**The question:** Am I doing the right way or should I use catkin workspace?

**Upadate 1**: The error was because I was not running this command `source devel/setup.bash` before `catkin_make` . Now it works. But if I import urdf file to Moveit Setup Assistant it will load only if it is on `opt/ros/indigo/share` if i load the urdf file from local work-space the urdf package with meshes is not found.

**The question 2:** What should I install to local work-space `catkin_ws/src` (if this is the right path)?

**Update 2**: catkin_make fails when I install [rviz_visual_tools](https://github.com/davetcoleman/rviz_visual_tools/tree/indigo-devel) and  [moveit_tutorials](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit_tutorials/tree/indigo-devel) on `catkin_ws/src`
Info:

```
student@:~/catkin_ws$ source devel/setup.bash
student@:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/student/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/student/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/student/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/student/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/student/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/student/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/student/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/student/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- This workspace overlays: /home/student/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/indigo
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/student/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.6.18
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 4 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - assem_moveit_config
-- ~~  - rviz_visual_tools
-- ~~  - moveit_visual_tools
-- ~~  - moveit_tutorials
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'assem_moveit_config'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(assem_moveit_config)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'rviz_visual_tools'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(rviz_visual_tools)
CMake Warning at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:76 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "graph_msgs" with
  any of the following names:

    graph_msgsConfig.cmake
    graph_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "graph_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "graph_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "graph_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  rviz_visual_tools/CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package)


-- Could not find the required component 'graph_msgs'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /opt/ros/indigo/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "graph_msgs" with
  any of the following names:

    graph_msgsConfig.cmake
    graph_msgs-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "graph_msgs" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "graph_msgs_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "graph_msgs" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  rviz_visual_tools/CMakeLists.txt:13 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/student/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/student/catkin_ws/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250251/when-should-i-use-catkin-workspace?/) by [peter1234](https://answers.ros.org/users/28691/peter1234/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2016-12-17

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Until you are more comfortable with ROS and Catkin, I'd *always* create a Catkin workspace in your home directory and do all your development in/from there.

*Never* (*) move packages to `/opt/ros/$distro`: it's certainly possible to store whatever you want there, but it's likely that you'll do it incorrectly, leading to all sorts of weird and hard to debug problems. Besides: you must have had to either use `sudo ..` to get the files there, or have run the Setup Assistant as `root`. It's typically a red flag if you ever need super user rights to do anything in ROS (it's almost a second *never* (*)).

Treat `/opt/ros/$distro` as a no-go area, [create a workspace](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace) and put your own packages in that workspace. Know btw that you'll only have to `source` your own `devel/setup.bash`: no need to source the one in `/opt/ros/$distro` every time as well (do it once, before you `catkin_make` / `catkin build` your workspace).

> If  I [..] run `cakin_make` and launch [..] `roslaunch home/name/catkin_ws/src/<package_name>/launch/demo.launch` it gives many errors.

And another tip: please include examples of any errors you get when you ask us questions. We can't know what is going wrong for you, and this makes it very hard for us to help you.

*) well, 'never'. But for now, no, *never*.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [peter1234](https://answers.ros.org/users/28691/peter1234/) on 2016-12-19**:
Look on my update please

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-12-19**:
I don't have time to answer everything right now, but your missing packages are caused by the fact that you didn't install all prerequisites.

Run a `rosdep update && rosdep install --from-paths /home/student/catkin_ws/src --ignore-src`, then try building again.